# Error regarding loading status , searched and may be its due to chrome version or any other issue

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

i am runnig this script on an ecommerce website and everytime i get different errors like
cannot determine loading status error i am sharing my code java and chrome version and console error

java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)

Chrome is up to date
Version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853}) on port 60257
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jul 15, 2022 12:53:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
Jul 15, 2022 12:53:31 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found exact CDP implementation for version 103
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'AWAIS-PC', ip: '192.168.1.62', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [74937cfc60537254dd31ccbbd06cff36, findElement {using=id, value=wzrk-cancel}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 103.0.5060.114, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd7..., userDataDir: C:\Users\WRP\AppData\Local\...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:65159}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:65159/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.114, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 74937cfc60537254dd31ccbbd06cff36
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:387)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:379)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at First_Test.Practice_First.main(Practice_First.java:50)

public class Practice_First {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Driver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
          WebDriverWait waits=new WebDriverWait (driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15));
            
    
        driver.get("https://www.ounass.ae/");
        
        
        //Thread.sleep(3000);
        
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
     
        waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("wzrk-cancel")));
                   driver.findElement(By.id("wzrk-cancel")).click();
                   
                   
                 
            
                   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/men']")).click();
            
           
      
                   JavascriptExecutor Js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                Js1.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,2500)"); 
          
            
              
                
                
            waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[text='Billionaire Boys Club']")));
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[text='Billionaire Boys Club']")).click();
            
              
         
             waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[title='Blue']")));
                    
       
             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[title^='Blue']")).click();
             
             waits.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[class^='Select-control']")));
             
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Select-control']")).click();
          
           
          
           
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='XL']")).click();
           
           driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-cy^='addToBagButton']")).click();
           
             Thread.sleep(2000);
             waits.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[class='Select-control']")));
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Select-control']")).click();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='L']")).click();
           
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-cy^='addToBagButton']")).click();
        
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/cart']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [SLF4J documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder), these are options to avoid the warning you've encountered:

"This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem."